# The pid works only once after the two calls to scanf

Tags: c, ipc, semaphore

This program creates a pid and shares two integers (base and height) through the shared memory.

The parent process time asks four times to insert two integers and wait for the pid to calculate the area.

After the four cycles, the ppid waits for the end of its child, deletes the shared memory and the semaphore and ends. The child waits for the new variable (base, height with semaphore), calculates the area, and prints it, and after the four iterations, it ends.

I have to use semaphore for process synchronization and to regulate the critical section. The problem consists of the pid, it works only one time.

I'm expected to receive the area after i put the integer, the first time work but the following time doesent.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SEM_KEY (key_t)8765
#define SHM_KEY (key_t)9876

/** Questa union la trovate digitando "man semctl" */
union semun
{
    int val;               /* Value for SETVAL */
    struct semid_ds *buf;  /* Buffer for IPC_STAT, IPC_SET */
    unsigned short *array; /* Array for GETALL, SETALL */
    struct seminfo *__buf; /* Buffer for IPC_INFO(Linux-specific) */
};

/** Tipo di dato condiviso */
struct sh_data
{
    int altezza;
    int base;
};

/** Funzioni di appoggio per operare con i semafori */
int sem_set(int semid, int val);
int sem_down(int semid);
int sem_up(int semid);

void controlla_area(int, struct sh_data *);

int main()
{
    pid_t pid;
    int semid, shmid, i;
    struct sh_data *data;

    // SEMAFORO
    // Creazione del semaforo
    semid = semget(SEM_KEY, 1, 0666 | IPC_CREAT);

    // Inizializzazione semaforo
    sem_set(semid, 1);

    // SHARED MEMORY
    // Creazione shared memory
    shmid = shmget(SHM_KEY, sizeof(struct sh_data), 0666 | IPC_CREAT);

    // Attach della shm allo spazio di indirizzi del processo
    data = (struct sh_data *)shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);

    // Processo figlio
    pid = fork();
    switch (pid)
    {
    case -1:
        perror("Errore fork");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    case 0:
        controlla_area(semid, data);
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    default:
        break;
    }

    // Processo padre
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        sem_down(semid);
        printf("Inserisci la base: ");
        scanf("%d", &(data->base));
        printf("Inserisci l'altezza: ");
        scanf("%d", &(data->altezza));
        sem_up(semid);
        wait(NULL);
    }

    // Detach della shared memory
    shmdt(data);

    // Eliminazione della shared memory
    shmctl(shmid, IPC_RMID, NULL);

    // Eliminazione semaforo
    semctl(semid, 0, IPC_RMID);

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

void controlla_area(int semid, struct sh_data *data)
{
    int area;

    sem_down(semid);
    area = data->base * data->altezza;
    printf("L'area del triangolo è %d\n", area);
    sem_up(semid);
}

int sem_set(int semid, int val)
{
    union semun s;
    s.val = val;
    /* Inizializza il valore del semaforo */
    return semctl(semid, 0, SETVAL, s);
}

int sem_down(int semid)
{
    struct sembuf buff;
    buff.sem_num = 0;
    buff.sem_op = -1;
    buff.sem_flg = SEM_UNDO;
    /* Decrementa il valore del semaforo */
    return semop(semid, &buff, 1);
}

int sem_up(int semid)
{
    struct sembuf buff;
    buff.sem_num = 0;
    buff.sem_op = 1;
    buff.sem_flg = SEM_UNDO;
    /* Incrementa il valore del semaforo */
    return semop(semid, &buff, 1);
}
```

Comment: Code does not compile, btw.

Comment: `scanf("%d", &data.base[i]);` (also: you'l need to consume the `'\n'`)

Comment: what is the purpose of the union?

Comment: @stark : the sem_un is from Stevens's APUE. (it is also in the man page)

Comment: The code does not compile. It has numerous syntax/grammar errors. Possibly you attempted to prepare a [mre] instead of posting original code, which is good, but you did not get the [mre] working.

Comment: i've uploaded the correct code,now it should work

Comment: `warning: ‘i’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]`

Comment: `for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)`

Comment: `scanf()` without checking return value -> undefined behavior due to uninitialized variable waiting to happen.

Comment: @wildplasser "need to consume the '\n'" is unclear as `scanf("%d", &data.base[i]);` consumes leading '\n'.

Answer (score 1):

> The problem consists of the pid, it works only one time.

This is because the *child* process calls `controlla_area` just **once**, and executes its contents

```
void controlla_area(int semid, struct sh_data *data)
{
    int area;

    sem_down(semid);
    area = data->base * data->altezza;
    printf("L'area del triangolo è %d\n", area);
    sem_up(semid);
}
```

just **once**, and then exits.

Note that both the *parent* process and the *child* process will vie for control of the shared memory via the semaphore. There is no guarantee as to which process will first decrement the semaphore, but it is likely the *parent* process will, due to the overhead of starting a new process (see also: [context switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch)).

The fact that the *child* process does surely gain access to the semaphore is made possible by the [`wait(NULL);`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait.2.html) that blocks the execution of the *parent* process, during the first iteration of the loop that writes to shared memory, until the *child* process terminates.

Placing a blocking action in the *parent* process, after the `switch` statement (e.g., [`sleep(5)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sleep.3.html)) will make the *race condition* obvious. The *child* process will likely get some CPU time, and will gain access to the shared memory via the semaphore decrement. It will then invoke [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior) by reading the indeterminate values in the shared memory.

Incrementing a semaphore is not a blocking action. There is no guarantee that the process that just incremented the semaphore will not be the same process to next decrement the semaphore. This is a matter of scheduling, and is implementation defined.

A single semaphore should not be relied upon to create this kind of synchronization between processes.

---

With minimal changes, an *additional semaphore* can create a *lockstep* between the *parent* process and the *child* process, such that each process waits for the other to complete its work.

A loop is added to the *child* process.

The semaphores are initialized such that the *parent* process operates first. The additional `sem_down(semid_to);` ensures the *parent* process waits for the *child* process to finish printing, before terminating it via a signal.

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
#include <signal.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <string.h>


#define SEM_KEY (key_t)8765
#define SHM_KEY (key_t)9876

/** Questa union la trovate digitando "man semctl" */
union semun
{
    int val;               /* Value for SETVAL */
    struct semid_ds *buf;  /* Buffer for IPC_STAT, IPC_SET */
    unsigned short *array; /* Array for GETALL, SETALL */
    struct seminfo *__buf; /* Buffer for IPC_INFO(Linux-specific) */
};

/** Tipo di dato condiviso */
struct sh_data
{
    int altezza;
    int base;
};

/** Funzioni di appoggio per operare con i semafori */
int sem_set(int semid, int val);
int sem_down(int semid);
int sem_up(int semid);

void controlla_area(int, int, struct sh_data *);

int main()
{
    pid_t pid;
    int semid_to, semid_from, shmid, i;
    struct sh_data *data;

    // SEMAFORO
    // Creazione del semaforo
    semid_to = semget(SEM_KEY, 1, 0666 | IPC_CREAT);
    semid_from = semget(1 + SEM_KEY, 1, 0666 | IPC_CREAT);

    // Inizializzazione semaforo
    sem_set(semid_to, 1);
    sem_set(semid_from, 0);

    // SHARED MEMORY
    // Creazione shared memory
    shmid = shmget(SHM_KEY, sizeof(struct sh_data), 0666 | IPC_CREAT);

    // Attach della shm allo spazio di indirizzi del processo
    data = (struct sh_data *)shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);

    // Processo figlio
    pid = fork();
    switch (pid)
    {
    case -1:
        perror("Errore fork");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    case 0:
        controlla_area(semid_to, semid_from, data);
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    default:
        break;
    }

    // Processo padre
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        sem_down(semid_to);
        printf("Inserisci la base: ");
        scanf("%d", &(data->base));
        printf("Inserisci l'altezza: ");
        scanf("%d", &(data->altezza));
        sem_up(semid_from);
    }

    sem_down(semid_to);
    kill(pid, SIGTERM);
    wait(NULL);

    // Detach della shared memory
    shmdt(data);

    // Eliminazione della shared memory
    shmctl(shmid, IPC_RMID, NULL);

    // Eliminazione semaforo
    semctl(semid_to, 0, IPC_RMID);
    semctl(semid_from, 0, IPC_RMID);

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

void controlla_area(int semid_to, int semid_from, struct sh_data *data)
{
    int area;

    while (1) {
        sem_down(semid_from);
        area = data->base * data->altezza;
        printf("L'area del triangolo è %d\n", area);
        sem_up(semid_to);
    }
}

int sem_set(int semid, int val)
{
    union semun s;
    s.val = val;
    /* Inizializza il valore del semaforo */
    return semctl(semid, 0, SETVAL, s);
}

int sem_down(int semid)
{
    struct sembuf buff;
    buff.sem_num = 0;
    buff.sem_op = -1;
    buff.sem_flg = SEM_UNDO;
    /* Decrementa il valore del semaforo */
    return semop(semid, &buff, 1);
}

int sem_up(int semid)
{
    struct sembuf buff;
    buff.sem_num = 0;
    buff.sem_op = 1;
    buff.sem_flg = SEM_UNDO;
    /* Incrementa il valore del semaforo */
    return semop(semid, &buff, 1);
}
```

---

Note that there are *many* things that could go wrong here, due to the fact that almost no error handling is done whatsoever. `semget`, `semctl`, `semop`, `shmget`, `shmat`, `shmctl`, `shmdt`, `scanf`, `kill` and `wait` can all **fail**.

In a non-trivial program none of these return values should be ignored with regards to errors.